# Its possible to retrieve the components published under a specific folder and filter by lastPublishDate?

Tags: graphql

```
query GenericQuery {
items(
    filter: {itemTypes: [COMPONENT], publicationIds: [1], schema: {id: 460}}
) {
    edges {
        node {
            itemId
            title
            lastPublishDate
            publicationId
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for this information on CM or DXD?